# Evaluating a trigonometric integral with square root

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I want to evaluate the integral

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+a\cdot \cos(x)} ~dx$  where $|a| \leq 1$.

I have already tried to split the integral using the periodicity of $\cos$ into

$ \int_0^{\pi} \left( \sqrt{1+a\cdot \sin(x)} + \sqrt{1-a\cdot \sin(x)} \right) ~dx$,
but that does not seem to make things easier.

Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are entering the world of elliptic integrals.

Start using $\cos(x)=1-2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ to make
$$I=\int \sqrt{1+a\, cos(x)}\,dx=\int\sqrt{(1+a)-2 a \sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\,dx$$
$$I=\sqrt{1+a}\int\sqrt{1-\frac{2 a }{1+a}\sin ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\,dx$$ Now, let $x=2y$
$$I=2\sqrt{1+a}\int\sqrt{1-\frac{2 a }{1+a}\sin ^2\left(y\right)}\,dy$$
Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Answer (score 3):

Unless $a = 1$ exactly, your integral is what turns out to be an Elliptic integral. No analytical solution can be found. Yet it is a well know integral. Indeed in literature we have that

$$\int \sqrt{1 + a\cos(x)}\ \text{d}x = 2 \sqrt{a+1} E\left(\frac{x}{2}|\frac{2 a}{a+1}\right)$$

As long as $a > 0$.

The notation $E\left( \cdot | \cdot \right) $ denotes the Elliptic integral of the second kind.

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind

In your case, it is well known that

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1 + a \cos(x)}\ \text{d}x = 4 \sqrt{a+1} E\left(\frac{2 a}{a+1}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! I do see now, how to express my integral in terms of the complete elliptic integral E(.). So far, I can express it as $2 \left( \sqrt{1+a} E(\frac{2a}{a+1}) + \sqrt{1-a}  E(\frac{2a}{a-1}) \right)$ but I don't yet see, how this can be compressed further. Is there some property of $E$ that I am missing?

Comment: @etkm Unfortunately there is no way to make your expression simpler, unless you are dealing with special cases. For example: if $a = 0$ then it all reduces to $2\pi$ which is the exact result of the trivial integral (but $a$ cannot be zero for what you wrote in the conditions). 
The problem fo your expression is that it's wrong. For example: if $a = 1$ your expression returns an indeterminate result where as mine returns $4\sqrt{2}$ which would be the exact result of $\int \sqrt{1+\cos(x)}\ \text{d}x$ with extrema $[0, 2\pi]$. How did you get your expression?

Comment: You are right, I used the definition of $E(.)$ incorrectly. By using the symmetry of $\cos$ and the suggested substitution, I could also find your result. Why does my condition exclude $a=0$? I wanted this expression for $-1 \leq a \leq 1$.